# Jest - enzyme testing warning: Failed prop type

Tags: reactjs, redux, jestjs, enzyme

Doing testing with `jest` and `enzyme` and I think I am doing everything right but somehow getting the warning:

> Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `project` is marked as required in `ProjectPageUI`, but its value is `undefined`.
>             in ProjectPageUI

Here is how the test looks like:

```
test('shallow-render without crashing', () => {
  /*  
    project: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
   */

  const props = { 
    match: { params: {} },
  }
  const store = configureStore()(STATE_WITH_2_FAMILIES)
  shallow(<ProjectPageUIComponent store={store} {...props} />)
})
```

Inside `ProjectPageUI.jsx` I get `project` property using the selector:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => ({
  project: getCurrentProject(state),
})
```

Where `getCurrentProject` is the following:

```
export const getProjectsByGuid = state => state.projectsByGuid
export const getProjectGuid = state => state.currentProjectGuid

export const getCurrentProject = createSelector(
  getProjectsByGuid, getProjectGuid, (projectsByGuid, currentProjectGuid) => projectsByGuid[currentProjectGuid],
)
```

In the `STATE_WITH_2_FAMILIES` I have both `projectsByGuid` and `currentProjectGuid` defined and `projectsByGuid` has the respective key for `currentProjectGuid` and the object defined. So, now I am wondering why is this warning happenning and how I should change my test, since I would expect it to have no issues at all: the selector gets `project` from the `state` and it should be `defined`.

> Clarification

Thats how the `ProjectPageUI` looks like:

```
const ProjectPageUI = (props) => {
    ...
    ...
    return ( ... )
}

ProjectPageUI.propTypes = { 
  project: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  ...
  ...
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => ({
  project: getCurrentProject(state),
  ...
  ...
})

export { ProjectPageUI as ProjectPageUIComponent }

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ProjectPageUI)
```

Comment: What is `ProjectPageUIComponent`? Is that something different than `ProjectPageUI`? You may just need to create a wrapper that takes the store (i.e. redux provider) that your component connects to and not pass it directly to the component under test.

Comment: I am exporting the component as `export { ProjectPageUI as ProjectPageUIComponent }` So, its the component itself and nothing else.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! It helped to solve it faster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you export your raw component

```
export { ProjectPageUI as ProjectPageUIComponent }
```

You can test it directly without the need to mock up a redux provider and store

```
import { ProjectPageUIComponent } from '.'; // import raw component

...

test('shallow-render without crashing', () => {

  const props = { 
    match: { params: {} },
    project: { /* now mock up a project object for testing */ }
    // mock/supply any other required props
  }

  shallow(<ProjectPageUIComponent {...props} />)
});
```

Have you considered `react-testing-library`? IMO it is a much cleaner way to test UI components. For a simple "renders without crashing" test it is very similar to the above.

Answer (score 1):

Try to wrap you component with redux Provider component
The  makes the Redux store available to any nested components that have been wrapped in the connect() function.

```
shallow(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ProjectPageUIComponent {...props} />
  </Provider>)
```

Comment: Does a shallow mount here still render the wrapped child? Typically it'll render the root component and no children, IIRC.

Comment: I was able to fix other failing tests using your advice, so thanks a lot! However, this warning it does not eliminate. The thing is that the test I asked about is not failing, but the warning is still there which tells me that smth is wrong still.

Comment: @DrewReese - I am new to testing, so I don't know but it seems not. Would then it mean that such wrapping would test how `Provider` renders instead of the actual component?..

Comment: after replacing shallow with mount you can find your desire component by it's name and then run your tests
const wrapper = shallow(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ProjectPageUIComponent {...props} />
  </Provider>)

const ProjectPageUI = wrapper.find('ProjectPageUI')

Comment: It does not fix it. If I change to `mount` and add `Provider` the warning remains, but the test stops passing, having an error in some of its children (unrelated issue to current question but still. Maybe it is not right and I need to test here only the root)

Answer (score 1):

Pretty stupid, but it was an issue of wrong importing of the `ProjectPageUI`. I imported it as:

```
import { ProjectPageUIComponent } from './ProjectPageUI'
```

which imports the unconnected component, but should have imported the defaults' way:

```
import ProjectPageUI from './ProjectPageUI'
```

Which worked out

Comment: Ah yes, this will work as well. Should've refreshed my screen before providing my answer.